# $http GET request in Node/Angular receives weird response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, node.js, mean-stack

When I call a get request, I am getting the ngRepeat:Dupes error because what my get request is getting me from a console.log shows me the hard-coded html code from the page itself.

Here is the console.log

```
mainController.js:10 <!DOCTYPE>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Social Network Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" ng-controller="navigationController">
        <div class="container">
            <div ng-show="!loggedIn">
                <input type="text" ng-model="login.email">
                <input type="password" ng-model="login.password">
                <button ng-click="logUserIn()">Login</button>
                <a ui-sref="signUp">Create An Account</a>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="loggedIn">
                <a ui-sref="editProfile">Edit Profile</a>
                <a ng-click="logOut()">Logout</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div ui-view></div>

    <!--Libraries-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

    <!--Controllers-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="partials/signup/signupController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="partials/navigation/navigationController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="partials/profile/editProfileController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="partials/main/mainController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My client side controller shows the following code:

```
var getTweets = function(initial){
        $http.get('/tweets').then(function(response){
            if(initial){
                $scope.tweets = response.data;
            } else {
                $scope.incomingTweets = response.data;
            };
        });
    };
    getTweets(true);
```

and my server side api function is the following:

```
router.get('/tweets', tweetController.getTweets);
```

lastly the server side controller is the following:

```
module.exports.getTweets = function(req,res){
console.log("works");
Tweet.find({}).sort({date: -1}).exec(function(err, data){
    if(err) {
        throw err;
        res.json({status: 500});
    } else {
        console.log(data);
        res.json(data);
    };
});
};
```

What did I do wrong?

The console.log on the server side doesn't show "works" meaning the request didn't even reach the server but for some reason the client side got a response.

Comment: `mainController.js:10` and what about this file and that line? seems your answer should be found there

Comment: Hi @VictorPerov that is where I have put in the console.log function in order to see what response I am getting from the server.

Comment: so, you are trying to print `"works"` but receive html of your page? It means that your web-server can be miss-configured. But I can't help you without understanding all points. Try to change `throw err` in your web-server controller to `console.log(err);` for test purpose.

Comment: No  @VictorPerov, I tried doing console.log(response.data) on the client side, but what actually does is it doesnt even get to the server side. Console.log("works") should print "works" on my server console but it does not and the console.log("response.data") prints the console data up above.

Comment: Are you sure that this `module.exports.getTweets = function(req,res){` is correct? In nodejs should be your `tweetController`, not `module`. Or have you renamed `module`?

Comment: Default landing page (probably `index.html`) can be showed as result of variously situations

Answer (score 0):

The server probably returned an error page. Inspect the html that was returned to see what's going on, it probably contains some information.

Debug your app by executing the url `/tweets` in the browser or Postman (or use Chrome dev tools). If the server doesn't return json, either the url is wrong or something is wrong server side. That eliminates a bug in the client side.

Comment: `/tweets` is not routed anywhere so it wouldn't show me anything in the browser. I have personally routed the `/tweets` get request both client side and server side but the server side never received the request.

Comment: I mean the full url of course. Assuming the client and server run on the same port, try executing http://localhost:[port]/tweets

Comment: I understood what you meant but in node.js "/tweets" is not routed anywhere. So by going to "/tweets" I am in a sense going to get an error 404.

Comment: If /tweets is not routed anywhere, how do you expect to get any result when calling $http('/tweets')? Have you inspected the html that is returned? My guess is that it is a 404 error page

Comment: The html it returns is of my basic view page, if you see the code above you will see what i mean. It is routed in the server but not the actual link. It's just routed to a function that accesses the database.

Comment: I have POST functions done the same way that work perfectly fine, but for some reason the GET functions are returning the same problem. Keep in mind this is a node.js server and not php.